# CSS background image outside container

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble with my worpdress/bootstrap navigation to highlight current page.

[image: See my menu css problem please]

I'm trying to find the best workaround, here is what's my method for now, but not working

- Make bottom-border on link
- Have a margin or padding or any kind of space on container and add background image at the bottom of it

unfortunately the image won't display as soon as it should overlap the border.

Do you have any quick fix or other approach for this ?

Maybe I thought in order to expand the container, is to fix both link and container height and have them placed how I want...

Comment: Can you please add some code (html/css) ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/cgs6a11b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangle must be provided as absolute block. It can use :after.

Also for triangle you can use css(not image)

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
li{
  display: inline-box;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.active{
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
/*triangle absolute position and centred*/
.active:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent     transparent;
}
```

https://codepen.io/flinius/pen/XgyLba

Comment: ... And that works like a charm, thank you very much !